# Can I set multiple strings as the parameter for SQL Query in Looker Studio?

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I am trying to connect my data from BigQuery to Looker Studio. I want to filter an event based on the platforms (iOS, Android, Web). my Custom SQL Query in Looker Studio is like this

```
SELECT event_name, event_timestamp
FROM `project.analytics_111134888.events_*`
WHERE platform IN (@platform) <--- I use parameter in here
```

I define the `@platfrom` in Looker studio like this

[image]

I want to filter the query with these options. either select

1. Android Only
2. iOS Only
3. Web Only
4. All (Android + Web + iOS)

If Choose `Single Select` as the cardinality I will have no data show up on my Looker Studio if I choose `All`. If I change the cardinality to be `Multi-Select` then I can't even connect my BigQuery to Looker Studio, it will be error, maybe because the SQL type is `ARRAY<STRING>`

so, Can I set multiple strings as the parameter for SQL Query in Looker Studio? how to do something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I change the cardinality to be Multi-Select then I can't even connect my BigQuery to Looker Studio, it will be error, maybe because the SQL type is `ARRAY<STRING>`

Would you try below for `Multi-Select` ?

```sql
SELECT event_name, event_timestamp
FROM `project.analytics_111134888.events_*`
WHERE platform IN UNNEST(@platform) --<--- I use parameter in here
```

##### Test Custom SQL

```sql
SELECT platform
FROM UNNEST(['ANDROID', 'IOS', 'WEB']) platform
WHERE platform IN UNNEST(@platform) --<--- I use parameter in here
```

[image]

Comment: yup, it works. Thank you very much. I use `WHERE platform IN UNNEST(@platform)` with `Multi-Select` parameter like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XcAb.png